# How to cancel a long running WCF requests from silverlight 3

Tags: wcf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a silverlight 3 application that makes several long running requests to a WCF service. While these calls are in progress, any other later WCF calls are queued by silverlight 3 because it will only do two requests at the same time, thus making the application suck :(

How can I cancel the long running blocking requests?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I'm aware of is unfortunately to call `Abort()` on your proxy, but be careful, you need to create a new instance of it afterwards (and resubscribe to the Completed events) because it closes the underlying connection. Also note that this will kill *all* current async requests, so you need to call it before calling additional ones.

Answer (score -1):

Not directly answer your question, but you can make more than two simultaneous outgoing http requests.

If your application makes a lot of outgoing http requests, you will be throttled by .Net. By default, .Net only supports two simultaneous outgoing http requests. To get around that, you need to add a system.net section to app.config.

Here is an example snippet.

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
        <proxy usesystemdefault="false" bypassonlocal="true" />
        <bypasslist>
            <add address = "[^.]+\.[^.]+\.ntwk\.msn\.net$" />
            <add address = "[^.]+\.phx\.gbl$" />
        </bypasslist>
    </defaultProxy>
    <connectionManagement>
        <add address = "*" maxconnection = "12" />
    </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Does this apply to Silverlight?

Comment: No, it doesn't apply to SL. SL uses the browser http stack by default, which is limited to 6 on IE, 6 on chrome, and some other number on FF. You can switch it to use the client http stack, but then you can't use cookies or the asp.net forms authentication, and you're still limited to 6, on all browsers.